# SQL Azure DB extremely slow today

Tags: azure-sql-database

I've been a **SQL Azure Database** user for some time (over a year). I have a mostly readonly 5GB database that fuels my website. Queries hit the database about once or twice a second, and response times are generally sub 100ms.

There have been a few times when performance for all queries goes down the toilet. Today for example, I awoke to alarms that the database was performing poorly. Simple queries that normally take 30ms are taking over 3 minutes! My load on the server is no greater than usual, so I attribute this decline in performance to my DB sharing an instance with one or more DBs from other Azure users.

To solve this problem, I copy the database to a new instance (`CREATE DATABASE NEW_DB AS COPY OF OLD_DB`), and point the website to the new instance. All is well until this happens the next time. In about a year's time, this has happened 4 or 5 times.

**My question**: does anyone have some advice on how to mitigate this? If this is just life under Azure, it's pretty unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: just realized that this question is from 2014. If you're still having issues, the questions and suggestions below may guide you in the right direction. If you've resolved the performance issues, feel free to share how any actions you may have taken to improve performance.

---

What tier are you on right now?

- Reference: http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/SQL-Azure-database-recommendations-and-best-practices

Are your users coming from different geographical regions? If so, are you using endpoint monitoring for the web app that accesses your SQL Azure db?

- Reference: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-monitor/#webendpointstatus

Have you tried reading through the official performance guide?

- Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn369873.aspx

Here's a 3rd-party writeup that mentions *"the differences in connectivity behavior or that SQL Azure resources get throttled when you overload the database require you to take such things into account and code your application to handle issues you may not have using traditional a SQL Server application."*

- Reference: http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/SQL-Azure-database-recommendations-and-best-practices

This article requires (free) email signup before reading the full article, but it may help you with some recommendations and best practices.

Hope that helps!